# indexing couchdb using elastic search

Tags: couchdb, elasticsearch

HI I have installed elasticsearch version 0.18.7 and configured couchdb according to [these instructions](http://www.elasticsearch.org/tutorials/2010/08/01/couchb-integration.html). I am trying to create indexing in the following way:

```
curl -XPUT '10.50.10.86:9200/_river/tasks/_meta' -d '{
  "type": "couchdb",
  "couchdb": {
    "host": "10.50.10.86",
    "port": 5984,
    "db": "tasks",
    "filter": null
  },
  "index": {
    "index": "tasks",
    "type": "tasks",
    "bulk_size": "100",
    "bulk_timeout": "10ms"
  }
}'
```

and got the message like,

```
{
  "ok": true,
  "_index": "_river",
  "_type": "tasks",
  "_id": "_meta",
  "_version": 2
}
```

when trying to access the url like

```
curl -GET 'http://10.50.10.86:9200/tasks/tasks?q=*&pretty=true'
```

then

```
{
  "error": "IndexMissingException[[tasks] missing]",
  "status": 404
}
```

Please guide me how to indexing couchdb using elasticsearch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where `es_test_db2` is coming from.  What's the output of this?

```
curl 10.50.10.86:9200/_river/tasks/_status\?pretty=1
```